# NER(Named Entity Recognition) Similarity between sentences in documents

Tags: python, similarity, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have been using spacy to find the NER of sentences.My problem is I have to calculate the NER similarity between sentences of two different documents. Is there any formula or package available in python for the same?

TIA

Comment: Please look into https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html

Comment: What do you mean by NER similarity?

Comment: Similar entities occuring in sentences across different documents. In a way, its similar to cosine similarity. But my question is is there a way to assign a separate weightage for those entities?

Comment: I wonder if you have any insights to share, specifically regarding the different weights for different entities. As I see it if there is a frequent entity that is similar between many documents it should be weighted lower in the similarity search, but looking for a more general and researched direction

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking, `how similar are two named entities`?

This is not so trivial, since we have to define what "similar" means.

If we use a naive bag-of-words approach, two entities are more similar when more of their tokens are identical.

If we put the entity tokens into sets, the calculation would just be the jaccard coefficient.

```
Sim(ent1, ent2) = |ent1 ∩ ent2| / |ent1  ∪ ent2|
```

Which in python would be:

```
ent1 = set(map(str, spacy_entity1))
ent2 = set(map(str, spacy_entity2))
similarity = len(ent1 & ent2) / len(ent1 | ent2)
```

Where `spacy_entity` is one of the entities extracted by spacy

We then just create entity sets `ent` by creating a set of the strings that represent them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been tackling the same problem and heres how I'm Solving.
Since youve given no context about your problem, ill keep the solution as general as possible

Links to tools:

1. Spacy [Spacy Similarity](https://spacy.io/api/lexeme#similarity)
2. Flair NLP: [Flair NLP zero shot few shot](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_10_TRAINING_ZERO_SHOT_MODEL.md)
3. Roam Research for research articles and their approach [Roam Research home page](https://roamresearch.com/)

#### DISCLAIMER: THIS IS A TRIAL EXPERIMENT. AND NOT THE SOLUTION

#### Steps:

1. try a Large language model with a similarity coefficient (Like GPT-3 or TARS) on your dataset
   (Instead of similarity you could also use the zero shot/few shot classification and then manually see the accuracy or compute it if you have labelled data)
2. I am then grab the verbs (assuming you have a corpus and not single word inputs) and calculating their similariy (attaching x-n and x+n words [exlude stopwords according to your domain] if x is position of verb)
   This step mainly allows you give more context to the large language model so it is not biased on its large corpus (this is experimental)
3. And finally Im grabbing all the named entities and hopefully their labels (Example India: Country/Location) And Ask the same LLM (Large Language model)  after youve *constructed its Prompt* to see how many of the same buckets/categories your entities fall into (probability comparison maybe)

Even if you dont reproduce these steps, what you must understand is that these tools give you atomic information about your raw input. you have to put mathematic functions to compare and make the algorithm
In my case im averaging all 3 similarity index of the above steps and ensuring that all classification is multilabel classification

And to validate any of this, human pattern matching maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You need probably http://uima.apache.org/d/uimacpp-2.4.0/docs/Python.html/ plus a CoNLL-U parser attached to it https://universaldependencies.org/format.html. With this approach NERs are based to a dictionary in UIMA Pipeline. You need to develop some proprietary NER search/match algorithms (in Python or in other supported language).

Comment: Some CoNNL-U annotators can be found here: http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe/